# Azure DevOps Usage suddenly showing as excessive

Tags: azure-devops

In the past couple of weeks all our team are experiencing rate limiting on DevOps.  They are getting the error message:

Your usage has exceeded our rate limiting thresholds. To maintain service availability for other users we're delaying your requests. View your usage on this organization. Please visit our documentation to learn more.

When investigating the usage reports, they are showing several users with improbable values such as counts of 50K to 100K in the last hour.

None of the users have changed their usage behaviour so has there been a change to the way it is measured?  Or is there an issue with usage being measured incorrectly?

Comment: What *is* their usage pattern? Do you have any external integrations that impersonate users and consume REST APIs?

Comment: usually migrate from service to service, large number work items queries will lead to the usage limit warning, and you could check out the application and command in the report to further the investigations

Comment: The usage has not changed over the last few months - there are no external integrations and suddenly most users are getting the warning.  Something must have changed in the way DevOps measures or there is an issue in the measurement.
All users are just viewing the work board and working with code repos - how that can feasibly generate 100000 count in an hour is beyond me!